# How to remove redundant code in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

```
def new
  @user = User.find(session[:this_user])
  @message = Message.new    
  @people= People.order("is_active DESC, first_name, last_name")
end
```

When the create action fails validation, I need to set up the above variables again, creating an action that looks like:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])  
  if @message.save
    redirect_to(messages_path, :notice => 'Message was successfully created.') 
  else
    @user = User.find(session[:this_user])
    @message = Message.new    
    @people= People.order("is_active DESC, first_name, last_name")
    render :action => "new" 
end
```

end

What is the proper way to remove redundant code (and DRY it)?

Also, the above approach causes the form to forget any input if the validation fails. Is there a better way to do it so that it remembers any information entered?

Rails 3.07, Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `@user = User.find(session[:this_user])` in a `before_action` like so:

```
class SomeController
  before_action :set_session_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  def set_session_user
    @user = User.find(session[:this_user])
  end
end
```

And `@people= People.order("is_active DESC, first_name, last_name")` could be a `scope` like so:

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sorted_by_active_and_name, -> { order("is_active DESC, first_name, last_name") }
end
People.sorted_by_active_and_name
```